# Please, how do I limit items in a json API call to only two with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api

I have a website on Google Blogger where I use JavaScript to get IPSW firmware files via the IPSW.ME API. I have successfully come out with a design to match my template but what I will like is to get only the first two items from the JSON response. I'm still not very good with JS. Will be happy if someone can enlighten me.
Here is the code I'm using

```js
function fetchData() {
fetch('https://api.ipsw.me/v4/device/iPad8,8')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    const html = data.firmwares.map(info => {
        return `
        <div class="ipsw-info">
        <table id='ipsw-td'>
        <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">Device:</span></td> 
          <td>iPad Pro 3 (12.9-inch, Cellular, 1TB Model) (${info.identifier})</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">Firmware Version:</span></td> 
          <td>iOS ${info.version} ( Build  ${info.buildid})</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">Released Date:</span></td>
          <td> ${info.releasedate}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">File MD5sum:</span> </td>
          <td><code>${info.md5sum}</code></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">File SHA1sum:</span> </td>
          <td><code>${info.sha1sum}</code></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">Signed IPSW:</span></td>
          <td> ${info.signed}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <center>
        <div class='dlBox'>
  <!--[ Change data-text='...' atribute to add new file type ]-->
  <span class='fT' data-text='IPSW'></span>
  <div class='fN'>
    <!--[ File name ]-->
    <span> Download for ${info.identifier}</span>
    <span class='fS'>Size: ${info.filesize} bytes</span>
  </div>
  
  <!--[ Download link (change href='...' atribute to add link download) ]-->
  <a class='button' aria-label='Download' href='${info.url}' rel='noreferrer' target='_blank'><i class='icon dl'></i></a>
</div>
</center>
<h4 style='color:blue; text-align:center'> Can't Download? Copy link from below, paste in a new tab to download</h4>
<div class='btnF'>
<input type="text" value="${info.url}" id="myInput" style='width:70%'>
<button class='button ln' onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()"><span><svg class='line' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><g><rect x='5.54615' y='5.54615' width='16.45385' height='16.45385' rx='4'></rect><path d='M171.33311,181.3216v-8.45385a4,4,0,0,1,4-4H183.787' transform='translate(-169.33311 -166.86775)'></path></g></svg></span>&nbsp;
  </button>
  </div>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000000000"
     data-ad-slot="2566286925"></ins>
        `;  
     })
    .join();
    console.log(html);
    document.querySelector('#ipsw-info').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
  });
}
fetchData()
```

Comment: `data.firmwares.slice(0,2).map(.....` [Array#slice documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use array slice
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```js
function fetchData(limit) {
fetch('https://api.ipsw.me/v4/device/iPad8,8')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    const html = data.firmwares.slice(0, limit).map(info => {
        return `
        <div class="ipsw-info">
        <table id='ipsw-td'>
        <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">Device:</span></td> 
          <td>iPad Pro 3 (12.9-inch, Cellular, 1TB Model) (${info.identifier})</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">Firmware Version:</span></td> 
          <td>iOS ${info.version} ( Build  ${info.buildid})</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">Released Date:</span></td>
          <td> ${info.releasedate}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">File MD5sum:</span> </td>
          <td><code>${info.md5sum}</code></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">File SHA1sum:</span> </td>
          <td><code>${info.sha1sum}</code></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><span  class="ios-data">Signed IPSW:</span></td>
          <td> ${info.signed}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <center>
        <div class='dlBox'>
  <!--[ Change data-text='...' atribute to add new file type ]-->
  <span class='fT' data-text='IPSW'></span>
  <div class='fN'>
    <!--[ File name ]-->
    <span> Download for ${info.identifier}</span>
    <span class='fS'>Size: ${info.filesize} bytes</span>
  </div>
  
  <!--[ Download link (change href='...' atribute to add link download) ]-->
  <a class='button' aria-label='Download' href='${info.url}' rel='noreferrer' target='_blank'><i class='icon dl'></i></a>
</div>
</center>
<h4 style='color:blue; text-align:center'> Can't Download? Copy link from below, paste in a new tab to download</h4>
<div class='btnF'>
<input type="text" value="${info.url}" id="myInput" style='width:70%'>
<button class='button ln' onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()"><span><svg class='line' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><g><rect x='5.54615' y='5.54615' width='16.45385' height='16.45385' rx='4'></rect><path d='M171.33311,181.3216v-8.45385a4,4,0,0,1,4-4H183.787' transform='translate(-169.33311 -166.86775)'></path></g></svg></span>&nbsp;
  </button>
  </div>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7092179791790867"
     data-ad-slot="2566286925"></ins>
        `;  
     })
    .join();
    console.log(html);
    document.querySelector('#ipsw-info').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
  });
}
fetchData(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the `API` supports data limitation like `LIMIT`.

If this is not supported you can do

```
const html = data.firmwares.slice(0,2).map(info => { ...
```

[SOURCE](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-get-first-two-elements-of-array)